# Proving theorem about basis for some topology

Tags: general-topology

Definition:Let $\tau$ be a topology on a set $X$, and let $\mathcal{B} \subset \tau$. Then $\mathcal{B}$ is a basis for the topology $\tau$ if and only if every open set in $\tau$ is the union of elements of $\mathcal{B}$. If $B \in \mathcal{B}$, we say $B$ is a basis element. Note that $B$ is an element of the basis of $\mathcal{B}$, but a subset of the set $X$.

Theorem(used in proof):

Let $(X,\tau)$ be a topological space, and let $\mathcal{B}$ be a collection of subsets of $X$. Then $\mathcal{B}$ is a basis for $\tau$ if and only if

$(1) \mathcal{B} \subset \tau$ and

$(2)$ for each set $U$ in $\tau$ and point $p$ in $U$ there is a set $V$ in $\mathcal{B}$ such that $p \in V \subset U$.

Theorem(trying to prove):Suppose $X$ is a set and $\mathcal{B}$ is a collection of subsets of $X$. Then $\mathcal{B}$ is a basis for some topology if and only if

$(1)$ each point of $X$ is in some element of $\mathcal{B}$ and

$(2)$ if $U$ and $V$ are sets in $\mathcal{B}$ and $p$ is a point in $U \cap V$, there is a set $W$ in $\mathcal{B}$ such that $p \in W \subset (U \cap V)$.

I am confident with the first part however the other direction of the biconditional has been confusing me.

($\Rightarrow$)

Since $\mathcal{B}$ is a basis, $X$ can be expressed as the union of elements of $\mathcal{B}$, so each point in $X$ is in some basis element. If $U,V \in\mathcal{B}$ since $U,V$ are open, $U \cap V$ is also open.Let $x \in U \cap V$. Since $U \cap V$ is open there exists a basis element $W$ such that $x \in W \subset U \cap V$.

($\Leftarrow$)

I have been struggling deciding what I need to show for this direction. Do I need to show for every point in every open set in $\tau$, there is a subset containing the point, contained in the open set, or do I need to show every element of $\tau$ can be expressed as a union of elements satisfying $(1)$ and $(2)$. Thinking about this, I realize it is wrong to already claim there is a set $\tau$, being a topology, without having proven it.

I will try and do the latter. Since each $x \in X$ is in a set satisfying $(1)$ and $(2)$, $X$ is the union of these sets. $\varnothing$ is in the union of these sets vacuously. I am having difficulty deciding what to do, to prove the second half of this theorem. Any hints will be appreciated.

Comment: Take $\tau = \{\bigcup_{\alpha\in \mathcal{A}} U_\alpha : U_\alpha\in \mathcal{B}\}$. Then $\mathcal{B}$ is a basis for $\tau$. Show that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The topology we define from $\mathcal{B}$ is $\tau$, the set of all unions of subfamilies of $\mathcal{B}$.

(1) says that $X \in \tau$ and $\emptyset$ follows as we can take the empty subfamily.

$\tau$ is closed under unions by construction (a union of unions is a union...)

If $U$ and $V$ are in $\tau$, we pick for each $x \in U \cap V$ some $B_1 \in \mathcal{B}$ such that $x \in B_1 \subseteq U$ ($B_1$ is from the subfamily than makes up $U$)
and some $B_2 \in \mathcal{B}$ such that $x \in B_2 \subseteq V$. (ditto for $V$).

Then $(2)$ tells us we can pick $B_x \in \mathcal{B}$ such that $x \in B_x \subseteq B_1 \cap B_2$.

But having done this for all such $x \in U \cap V$ we can easily see that $\bigcup \{B_x\mid x \in U \cap V\} = U \cap V$ (each $x \in U \cap V$ is in its "own" $B_x$, and hence in the union, for one inclusion and all $B_x \subseteq U \cap V$, hence so is the union, for the other), so we can also write $U \cap V$ as a union of a subfamily of $\mathcal{B}$, and so we're done checking $\tau$ is a topology.

Answer (score 3):

You have a family $\mathscr{B}$ of subsets of $X$ such that each $x\in X$ belongs to at least one $B\in\mathscr{B}$, and whenever $p\in U\cap V$, where $U,V\in\mathscr{B}$, there is a $W\in\mathscr{B}$ such that $p\in W\subseteq U\cap V$. You want to prove that $\mathscr{B}$ is a base for a topology $\tau$ on $X$. Since this is the case if and only if

$$\tau=\left\{\bigcup\mathscr{U}:\mathscr{U}\subseteq\mathscr{B}\right\}\,,\tag{1}$$

the natural approach is to **define** $\tau$ by $(1)$ and prove that $\tau$ is a topology on $X$. You’ve already observed that $\varnothing,X\in\tau$, so it remains to be shown that $U\cap V\in\tau$ whenever $U,V\in\tau$, and that $\bigcup\mathscr{U}\in\tau$ whenever $\mathscr{U}\subseteq\tau$.

It’s helpful to prove a small **lemma** first: if $B_0,B_1\in\mathscr{B}$, then there is a $\mathscr{U}\subseteq\mathscr{B}$ such that $B_0\cap B_1=\bigcup\mathscr{U}$ (and hence $B_0\cap B_1\in\tau$). I’ll leave this to you: it follows immediately from the second condition on $\mathscr{B}$.

Suppose that $U,V\in\tau$. Then there are $\mathscr{U},\mathscr{V}\subseteq\mathscr{B}$ such that $U=\bigcup\mathscr{U}$ and $V=\bigcup\mathscr{V}$. Then

$$\begin{align*}
U\cap V&=\left(\bigcup\mathscr{U}\right)\cap\bigcup\mathscr{V}\\
&=\bigcup_{B\in\mathscr{U}}\left(B\cap\bigcup\mathscr{V}\right)\\
&=\bigcup_{B\in\mathscr{U}}\bigcup_{C\in\mathscr{V}}(B\cap C)\,.\tag{2}
\end{align*}$$

By the lemma each of the sets $B\cap C$ in $(2)$ is the union of members of $\mathscr{B}$, so $U\cap V$ is a union of members of $\mathscr{B}$ and is therefore in $\tau$, as desired.

The proof that $\tau$ is closed under arbitrary unions is essentially the same as the last step of the previous argument.